# Label overflows window when using horizontal scrolling with chart_flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using charts_flutter and using a scrollable bar chart. Horizontal scrolling works great with the behaviors `SlidingViewport()` and `PanAndZoomBehavior()` ([charts_flutter example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/behaviors/sliding_viewport_on_selection)). I would also like to have labels follow the bar itself and stay inside the chart window when scrolling. See image.

[image]

Code

```dart
  BarChart(
    data,
    behaviors: [
      SlidingViewport(),
      PanAndZoomBehavior(),
    ],
    animate: true,
    domainAxis: OrdinalAxisSpec(
      viewport: OrdinalViewport('Week ${weeks.last}', 4),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I used ClipRect() to solve that issue, simply wrap your widget with what ever clipper you wish although the default works as well,

```
ClipRect(child : BarChart(
data,
behaviors: [
  SlidingViewport(),
  PanAndZoomBehavior(),
],
animate: true,
domainAxis: OrdinalAxisSpec(
  viewport: OrdinalViewport('Week ${weeks.last}', 4),
),
```

))